# How to calculate pharmacore features?

Tags: databases, docking, structural-biology

[Cross-posted at Bioinformatics.SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/22040/3621).

I want to use the enzyme ß-Glucuronidase with the [pharmit](https://pharmit.csb.pitt.edu/) database. I uploaded my file for the receptor from pdb file. How can I get the pharmacore features? So one thing is the enzyme is quiet popular, so is there any database with the features? I tried it with a [publication](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3092953/) but the given link is not working. It checked the site from the author but I did not found the database there.

And if there is no database or maybe there is one but the enzyme is not included, how can I get the pharmacore features for my calculations?

Comment: Also asked on bioinformatics SE: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/22040/how-to-calculate-pharmacore-features

Answer (score 0):

This was [answered at Bioinformatics.SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/22044/3621).

Therefore, I am removing it from our unanswered queue.